# If statement in a switch

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am working on a question for a course for learning javascript. I am running into trouble trying to add an if statement inside of a switch. I currently have:

```
var user = prompt("Are you ready for battle?!").toUpperCase();
switch(user) {
    case'YES':
        if(YES && NO) {
           console.log("Great, let's do it.");
        } else {
            console.log("Bye");
        }
        console.log("Great! It will be a long exciting battle.");
        break;  
    case'NO':
        console.log("Come back when you are ready.");
        break;
    case'MAYBE':
        console.log("Go away. This is only for the brave");
        break;
        default:
        console.log("You obviously do not belong here. It was a simple yes/no question.")
}
```

The question is this:

```
Add some if/else statements to your cases that check to see whether one
condition and another condition are true, as well as whether one condition 
or another condition are true. Use && and || at least one time each.
```

The error I am getting is this: `ReferenceError: YES is not defined`

What can I put in the if's condition to make this work or how do I define `YES`?

Comment: YES should be 'YES' and the same goes for NO. Not sure what you're doing really makes sense though.

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong `YES` is not defined. You have no variable named `YES` (or `NO` for that matter). If you'd meant `user == "YES"` then that's redundant (because your switch has taken care of it) and if you meant `user == "YES" && user == "NO"` then that makes no sense because it's always false (`user` can be *both* `YES` and `NO`)

Comment: Also why the logic can be `YES && NO` ?

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear

Comment: There is so much wrong in this switch. I think you need to re-examine your logic behind the code.

Comment: It looks like `'YES' && 'NO'` worked. Now I just have to create an OR statement. I'm not sure why it is having us do this. It is just a way to practice `&&`'s and `||`'s.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I'd say the problem is incredibly clear. `YES` is not defined because it is not defined as a variable, it's supposed to be a string. Clear issue to me.

Comment: @Becky: No it didn't "*work*". It might have run without a syntax error, but it's still completely wrong and doesn't make a lick of sense. `'YES'` and `'NO'` are constants, so your statement `'YES' && 'NO'` is *always true*. That is surely not what the intention was.

Comment: They had us create our own cases. If I new that I would be doing an if statement under it, I wouldn't have created a yes/no case. That is why this seems out of wack, but the course is just recognizing that we understand the `&&` and `||`

Comment: @Becky if the case matches 'YES', it will never be 'YES' and 'NO'. Although the logic is correct, it's entirely redundant.

Comment: You should probably be taking more inputs... you can't check multiple conditions because you only have one input. E.g. ask for age, gender, and "are you ready". Then use the switch to handle yes, no, maybe. Inside each case, you can do something like `if (age > 13 && gender == "f") { console.log("You rock, girl!"); }`.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: I'd say that this `What can I put in the if's condition to make this work` is not a clear problem statement. What does "work" mean? What's the code *supposed* to do? We can all see the immediate problem (`YES` isn't defined), but that surely isn't what is needed anyway.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - `if statement in a switch` && the `question` do not tell me anything - so, the problem statement is unclear.  The reason it doesn't compile is not the actual problem statement here.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you have two problems working against you here.

First is the issue pointed out in comments that you're treating `YES` and `NO` like variables, and they aren't. To avoid robbing you of the opportunity to learn by providing a corrected version of your code, I'll only give relevant examples.

```
var word = "test";
// If we compare against the string literally, it will have an error
// because it's looking for a variable with that name.
if (word === test) { } // ReferenceError: test is not defined

// we fix this by quoting what we're comparing against
if (word === "test") { } // Code inside the block would be executed :)

// But what about checking the value of "test" by itself?
// A string is "truthy", meaning that it passes the conditional test always.
if ("test") { } // Code would be executed always regardless of the content of var word

// Stringing multiple constants together doesn't make sense
if ("test" && "word") { } // This is equivalent...
if (true && true) { } // ... to this, which doesn't make sense
```

This brings us to the second problem you're trying to solve. The requirements for your problem specify checking if one condition AND another are true, as well as one condition OR another. The problem is that you only have one conditional to check: the status of the variable `user`.

It only makes sense to test the condition of something if you don't know what it is. Input received from a user is a perfect example. So I'd recommend that you take more inputs from the user such as name, age, gender, shoe size, or anything else. You can then check conditions as follows:

```
// You would need to store user input in variables username and age previously... 
if (username === "vastlysuperiorman" && age < 13) { console.log("You're awfully young!"); }

// Or to only allow people within an age range... 
if (age < 13 || age > 31) { console.log("You must be between 13 and 31 years old to play this game!"); }
```

Once you have multiple conditions to check, you can check them anywhere--inside a function, inside a case statement, inside another `if`. It doesn't matter. Just add an `if` block and test the conditions. :)